# ScrollToIndex does not scroll the FlatList as expected

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a FlatList setup like so

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.listContainer}
  data={this._formatList()}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  nestedScrollEnabled
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  extraData={this.state}
  ref={this._setRef}
/>
```

I also have these following two relevant functions in my component

```
_setRef = (ref) => {
  this._listref = ref;
}

_scrollToTop = () => {
  this._listref.scrollToIndex({ index: 0, animated: true });
}
```

I have checked that the this._listref is setup correctly when FlatList is rendered. 
The function _scrollToTop is called from a button click (and it is indeed called).

For some reason the list does not scroll to top as expected. 
I have tried various options playing with viewOffset / viewPosition.
It seems no scrolling action is taking place.

This is an expo project with "sdkVersion": "33.0.0"
and React and RN as follows from package.json
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex

> Note: Cannot scroll to locations outside the render window without
>   specifying the getItemLayout prop.

So you'll need to implement `getItemLayout` for scrolling to the top to work properly with `scrollToIndex` since most certainly it will be outside of the current render window.

You could alternatively use `scrollToOffset`: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltooffset with a param of `{offset: 0}` instead.

Comment: Thanks the doc could have been better, the scrollToIndex function puports a contract which is actually not exactly correct. BTW scrollToOffset({ offset: 0 }) also does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using offset?

`this.listRef.getNode().scrollToOffset({ offset: 0, animated: true });`

**OR**

`this.listRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 });`

Trying using this and I hope this will work assuming that you've correctly set up the reference of the scrollview and passing that correctly in the function.